# Javascript hasOwnProperty() return false even if it has property (Hackerrank Question)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand why hasOwnProperty return false even if it has the property.The

```
const pay = new Payment(285);
console.log(Payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'));
```

part is un-editable . So how can i have `console.log(Payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'))`;
log true instead of false.

i can only edit the Payment function .(Hackerrank Question)

```js
function Payment(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
  this.setAmount = (UpdatedAmount) => {
    return this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
  }
}
const pay = new Payment(285);
console.log(Payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'));
```

edit: Solved it by making following changes

```
function Payment(amount) {
      this.__proto__.amount = amount;
      this.__proto__.setAmount = (UpdatedAmount) => {
        return this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
      }
    }
    const pay = new Payment(285);
    console.log(Payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'));
```

Comment: Well, you are not adding it to the prototype, so it's an own property on the instance, not the prototype.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you want to extend the prototype of `Payment`, rather than defining a method on every single object:

```js
function Payment(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
}
Payment.prototype.setAmount = function (UpdatedAmount) {
  return this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
};
console.log(Payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'));
```

Note that you need a regular function, not an arrow-style function, in order to access `this` in `setAmount`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

```js
function Payment(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
  this.setAmount = (UpdatedAmount) => {
    return this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
  }
}
const p = new Payment()
console.log(p.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'));
```

Comment: Maybe it would be better to show how to add the method to the prototype, since that's what you usually want.

Comment: @Barmar Isn't `hasOwnProperty` somehow the opposite of a property in the prototype?

Comment: @jabaa The prototype can have its own "own" properties. That's what the question is trying to test.

Comment: in my original code i did something like `const pay = new Payment(15)` and then i tried to `console.log(payment.prototype.hasOwnProperty('setAmount'))` but it still returns false. am not able to change the console.log part since it is un-editable(hacerrank question)

Comment: @Barmar `.prototype.hasOwnProperty` checks only the first level prototype. I can't think of a use case for this. Either, I want to know if the object has an own property or I want to know if any prototype has a property. When would I use `.prototype.hasOwnProperty`?

Comment: @shivamsingh The point is that you should do `Payment.prototype.setAmount = ...`

Comment: @Barmar i don't actually have knowledge about prototype could you maybe tag some resources

Comment: @shivamsingh https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Answer (score 0):

Both `amount` and `setAmount` live in the **instance**, not in its `prototype`:

```js
function Payment(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
  this.setAmount = (UpdatedAmount) => {
    this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
    return this.amount;
  }
}
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Payment(100), 'setAmount'));
```

If you want it on the prototype, go ahead and define it there:

```js
function Payment(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
}

Payment.prototype.setAmount = function(UpdatedAmount) {
  this.amount = UpdatedAmount;
  return this.amount;
}
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(new Payment(100), 'setAmount'));
console.log(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Payment.prototype, 'setAmount'));
```